# How do I display Japanese glyphs in console?

Tags: terminal

Is there a way to configure the console to display Japanese *kanji*, *hiragana* and *katakana*? I can output as UTF-8.

Comment: It would just require setting the proper font. What distribution are you using and I can answer your question more specifically.

Comment: Actually, I found this: http://superuser.com/questions/380470/hiragana-console-font-for-gnu-linux I don't know enough about the subject to know if there's a way or not, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://ameblo.jp/mijyu-sakura/entry-11329029030.html, when I tried it, it fails at the last steps but otherwise will set up the locale and fonts. Then `jfbterm` and you can display UTF-8 encoded Japanese.

Comment: Please *explain* the link; don't give it. What happens if the link becomes void?

Comment: Thank you. What I did: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` added `ja_JP.EUC-JP EUC-JP` and `ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8` and made the last active. Then `sudo apt-get install ttf-kochi-gothic xfonts-intl-japanese xfonts-intl-japanese-big xfonts-kaname` then `sudo apt-get install jfbterm` and launched via `jfbterm -e [executable that outputs UTF-8]` and worked perfectly!